# Weird result difference in calculation with same numbers

Tags: c++

I have the following code (`m_threshold` (in interval [0..1]) and `binSize` (=1000) are constants):

```
std::vector<std::vector<ResidualEntry>> *bins = new std::vector<std::vector<ResidualEntry>>;
... //filling vector
int n = bins->size(); //is 27779
double a = -(2 * (n * binSize - m_threshold * pointCount)) / ((n * n + n) * binSize);
double a2 = -(2 * (bins->size() * binSize - m_threshold * pointCount)) / ((bins->size() * bins->size() + bins->size()) * binSize);
```

`a` and `a2` return completely different numbers. `a` is about 0.02 and `a2` is -3.6e-5 which is the correct one

Why does this happen?

Comment: Please create a [mcve].  From the help: _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."_

Comment: It would be nice to know the types of `binSize`, `m_threshold`, and `pointCount`.

Comment: Please review your equation for *integer division*.  *Integer division* truncates the results.  Try making your constants and variables in the equation `double`.

Comment: Also note that `vector::size()` returns a value of type `size_type` which should normally be an unsigned value, while int is a signed value, making the two lines completely different.

Comment: @SirDarius Thanks for pointing it out!! It works now... Implicit casts are not always the best idea ;)

Comment: What is `binsize`, `m_threshold`, `pointCount`? Please provide declarations and content of these variables. Is it possible that `binSize` is different from `bins->size()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @SirDarius: vector::size() returns a value of type size_type which should normally be an unsigned value, while int is a signed value, making the two lines completely different. After using size_t for initializing n, it all works now.